# How do Apple Enterprise certificates and their expiration dates work?

Tags: license, enterprise

I have a question that I wanted clarity on. As shown below, I have an Apple Enterprise account that has a membership expiration date of March 13, 2020

[image]

And within that membership, I have a Enterprise certificate that expires 2020/06/21, and another that expires 2022/10/01

[image]

This means that any provisioning profiles that I create will have to fit between now and a year out.

So if I make a provisioning profile that is linked to the certificate that expires 2020/06/21, given this is less than a year, the provisioning profile will expire on the same day the certificate expires (2020/06/21).  So this would be a bad idea.  However, a provisioning profile linked to the 2nd license of 2022/10/01, would expire a year from today-1.  So it would expire Oct 15, 2020.  This is the better idea.

And …. if I do not pay the membership fee of $299 on March 13, 2020 though, will both the certificates above also expire.  I would assume so.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

Edit:  I don’t know about enterprise certs what i said applies to normal developers but my understanding is that it is the same.

Certificate ls always expire in the date they say they will expire.  Your provisioning profile isn’t really important, you can delete and create them at will when ever you want. If you do not renew the $299 you cannot generate a new cert after your renew date.  Which means you won’t be able to create provisioning profiles either.

You can create new certs and provisioning profiles as often as you would like until your membership ends so these dates don’t really mean much. If both expire and you are still a member just create new ones.

Comment: Hi Tom,  Thanks for your help. This clarifies things a lot.  So if a user lets their membership expire, everything is dead.... if the certificates are set to expire later than the membership date... is this correct?

Comment: The expiration date is more for security and safety. They want you to generate new ones every so often (the industry sorta settled on 1yr) just in case yours got leaked or compromised in some way, or to validate that you're still alive.

The Certificates will be Revoked by Apple if you don't renew, rendering them useless regardless of expiration.

Comment: Perfect.  I am satisfied with this answer.